# Render success.js.erb personal_alert not displaying (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a button that is used to verify a user's zip code. When clicked, the desired functionality would be an alert display saying whether the zip code was verified or not.

```
<%= button_tag 'Verify zip code', :type => 'button', :id => 'self-install', remote: true %>
```

The alert file is in my Views and is in `zipcodes/success.js.erb` and `zipcodes/failure/js.erb`

This is my controller:

```
    if data.empty?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to page_path(submitted_page)
    end
    format.js do
      render 'zipcodes/failure'
    end
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to page_path(submitted_page)
    end
    format.js do
      render 'zipcodes/success'
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my ajax request:

```
$(function(){
$('#self-install').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: '/zipcodes/new',
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { zip: zipCodes },
  success: function(r){
  }
});
  });
});
```

When I click the button, my terminal says this:

[image]

**But nothing is displaying.** I am using Ruby on Rails. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there is anything I left out that would be helpful.

Comment: The `dataType` for the ajax request should be `script` I guess

Comment: That worked, thank the good lord! @AlexTatarnikov

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `remote: true` element, the ajax call in your js is unnecessary, besides your remote element should be a link_to with the respective url instead of button_tag

Resulting in the following code in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'new zipcode', new_zipcode_path, remote: true %>
```